# List<Task<Result>> All tasks have the same result

Tags: c#, list, task

I'm a newbie in C# and I have to write a little project for my education exam.

I have to read some sensors via telnet in a interval (500ms).
Therefore, I'm doing this by using the `task` class.
I generate a list of tasks on every cycle, wait until they are ready (after a timeout I cancel them by using a token), then I read out the results.
But all the results are the same, maybe they are all the first or the last task, which was responding.

Here is my snippet:

```
do
            {
                finished = false;
                activcnt = 0;
                tskcnt = 0;
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
/// generate Tasks               
                messcnt++;
                val.mscount = messcnt;
                sw.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < arrlengt; i++)
                {
                    if (clients[i] != null && clients[i].Connected && 
                        (parent._swork.lstSensor[i].sensState==1)  ) 
                    {
                        task2arr[tskcnt] = parent._swork.lstSensor[i].sensIdx;                    
                        tasks.Add(Messung(clients[i], parent._swork.lstSensor[i], val, ct));                        
                    }
                }
 /// wait until tasks are running     
               try {
                   if (!Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 400))
                   {
                       cts.Cancel();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       finished = true;
                   }
                }  catch (Exc.. e){..}          
                   time = (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
 /// result to list
                var results = new List<Values>(6);
                   foreach (var item in tasks)
                   {
                       results.Add(item.Result);
                   } 
                }
                _output.LogOutput(results);

                CheckErrorCnt(arrlengt, errcnt);

                tasks.Clear();
                time = (intervall - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Thread.Sleep((int)time);
                sw.Stop();                
                sw.Reset();
            }
           while (parent._gblset.measurestart == true);


private  Task<Values> Messung(TcpClient client , Sensor sens , Values val, CancellationToken ct )
        {
            string msg;

                return Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    int mscnt = val.mscount;                    
                    var _con = new Connecting();

                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        msg= sens.name+" : No response within specified time";
                        val.errstring = msg;
                        return val;
                    }

                   string response = _con.GetMeasure(client, ct);

                   val = parent._calc.GetValues(response, sens.kennIdx);
                   val.sensname = sens.name;
                   val.channame = sens.description;
                   val.sensidx = sens.sensIdx;
                   val.mscount = mscnt;

                   if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                   {
                       msg = "Error: " + sens.name + " : No response within specified time";
                       val.errstring = msg;
                       return val;
                   }
                    return val;
                });               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you verify your code snippet? It looks like you might be missing some parts of it (no catch after the try, for instance). I don't think this will even compile.

Comment: for this post  i reduced the snippet to the core. there is no error handling, and no exception handling. this works fine in my project.